# How to remove the black portion from the top of the given image and make is same as the other background?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, normalization

I am using openCV library. Histogram equalize or normalize will not give a good output, also the sharpness in bone will go down.

I need a output that has sharp bone without the black area at the top. Please help.

Also if my question is not clear, please feedback me so that i can make it more clear. Thank you for you support and suggestion.

[Picture link is here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9q80el4zhlky4o/1.bmp?dl=0)

Comment: I dont understand completely your question. But to know, which color space do you use to make the histogram equalization? I recommend you to use HSV and to equalize just the V layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.The given image is a gray scale image taken our from X-ray. Actually i want to remove the black portion in the given image. Furthermore, i want to increase the sharpness in the bone.

Comment: Do you know the black portion location in the picture? or does it change?

Comment: Yes, it changes. Normally it can be seen on the top region around the edge. This might be because of vignetting effect during the capture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the different illumination in different parts of image its common in X-ray image.
I think you need a adapted threshold for better results. 
Try divide the image in 2 parts. The centre and the borders. Apply the equalization in the centre and do the same in the borders region.

You can do in blocks to. This preserves the information along small tiles.
Look this:
[Equalization](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html#clahe-contrast-limited-adaptive-histogram-equalization)

Comment: Thank you  for your answer..I figured out the problem. Adapted threshold gave me a good result.